# How to remove or hide binding selected item from WPFlistview?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I bind some values to WPF listview.I want to remove or hide some row when click or select in row.I m try to do this one as follow.

listview.Items.RemoveAt(listview.Items.IndexOf(listview.SelectedItem));

but it's get exception.how to do this one? please help me......

Comment: If your list view is bound to a data list of items, you'll need to remove the item from the data list itself, not the list view. But that wouldn't necessarily be the cause of an exception. You'll really need to post some more code before we can really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MVVM pattern to achive it. You will need to create ObservableCollection, and then you can write command, wich will initialize with its collection, and when it should execute, it recieve object you need to delete via `{Binding}`. Its look like this:

```
//View model
public class FileGroupViewModel : ModelObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<FileGroup> fileGroups;
    public FileGroupViewModel ( ObservableCollection<FileGroup> _initialFileGroup )
    {
        this.fileGroups = _initialFileGroup;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileGroup> FileGroups
    {
        get
        {
            return fileGroups;
        }
        set
        {
            fileGroups = value;                
        }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteFileGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return new RemoveItemCommand<FileGroup>(FileGroups);
        }
    }
}
```

RemoveItemCommand - is templated class which implements ICommand interface

```
public class RemoveItemCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _items;
    public RemoveItemCommand(ObservableCollection<T> items)
    {
        _items = items;
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _items.Remove((T)parameter);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

then, your view will contain something like this^

```
<DataTemplate>
     <Button Command="{StaticResource DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: can you give another way for this one?

Comment: I need your code to modify it as less as possible, to avoid you from MVVM studeing.

Comment: I fix the problem using remove un wanted item from binding list and update listview again  form bind list.thanks your regard....